# Remainder Theorem, solve for K

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For what values of $k$ does the function $f(x) = x^3 + 6x^2 + kx – 4$ give the same 
 remainder when divided by $(x-1)$ and $(x + 2)$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Solve for $f(1)$ and $f(-2)$ and equate the two functions, that is $f(1)= f(-2)$, to solve for $K$.

Answer (score 0):

Remainder theorem tells us that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then the remainder of $f(x)$ when divided by $(x-a)$ is simply $f(a).$ Here, the respective remainders when divided by $(x-1)$ and $(x+2)$ will be $f(1)$ and $f(-2).$ All that you must do is find these values, set them equal to each other, and solve for $k.$

Answer (score 0):

Put $1$ and $-2$ in place of $x$, we should get the same number, so we have $$k + 3 = 12 - 2k.$$ Hence, $k = 3$.